# Parse original email address of the sender of a forwarded email in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Scenario:

user1 sent an email(Let's call it USER1-EMAIL) to user2

user2 forwarded the USER1-EMAIL to user3

user3 forwarded the USER1-EMAIL to user4

user4 forwarded the email to my email parser (Sendgrid Parse API)

what I wanted is to get the email of the original sender, which on this scenario is the email address of user1

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the [mail](http://rubygems.org/gems/mail) gem. Not only will it give you the From address, but it can give you all the other parts as well.

```
mail = Mail.read_from_string(email)

mail.from #=> ["original.sender@gmail.com"]
```

Comment: Probably better than mine. +1

Comment: This will give the address of user4 and not the original sender

Comment: @DeepakSharma Apparently I misread the question several years ago. My recommendation still holds, as the mail gem can pull any header. If the original sender exists in the message, the mail gem can retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

From what you posted alone I guess I would go with:

```
from = email[/From: .*<(.*?)>/, 1]
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know this syntax. Works with named captures, too. I love it!

Comment: this is great! follow up question, what if I have more than one
    From: Other Sender <other.sender@gmail.com>
    From: Original Sender <original.sender@gmail.com>
how it should be?

Comment: Would somebody mind explaining what's going on in this one liner? You're using regex and a  group / capture, but other than that, I'm clueless.

Comment: @rod - In that case you might use String#scan. nTraun - the (.*?) is a capture group with a non-greedy modifier, the 1 means return the first capture group.

Comment: @pguardiario 
Below is what I did using your regex to get the last From:
email.scan(/From: .*<(.*?)>/).flatten.last

I am not sure if what I did is dependable.